# Cálcula da soma da diferença entre 2 listas em Python

Tags: python

Eu preciso de uma função `compara_listas(lista1, lista2)` que receba duas listas aleatórias e calcule a soma da diferença entre os elementos delas. O porém é que se algum elemento da `lista2` for maior que a `lista1`, vai ficar negativo, e ele precisa ser positivo.

Como por exemplo:

```
(lista1 = [4.34, 0.05, 0.02, 12.81, 2.16, 0.0], lista2 = [3.96, 0.05, 0.02, 22.22, 3.41, 0.0])
```

Por exemplo o `(12.81 - 22.22)` e o `(2.16 - 3.41)` ficariam negativos. Então eu precisaria multiplicar por -1 para torná-lo positivo. Como fazer isso sem alterar os demais?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Em uma linha de código:

```
A = [4.34, 0.05, 0.02, 12.81, 2.16, 0.0]
B = [3.96, 0.05, 0.02, 22.22, 3.41, 0.0]

print(sum(abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(A, B)))
```

O resultado: `11.04`

**Como funciona?**

Primeiro, utilizamos a função nativa [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum), que retorna a soma dos elementos da lista passada por parâmetro. Para gerar esta lista - que é, na verdade, um iterador -, unimos as duas listas em um iterador de tuplas contendo os respectivos valores através da função nativa [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
>>> zip(A, B)
[(4.34, 3.96), (0.05, 0.05), ..., (0.0, 0.0)]
```

Após, iteramos sobre essa lista, efetuando a subtração entre os valores e calculando o valor absoluto do resultado, de forma que valores negativos fiquem positivos:

```
>>> abs(a - b) for a, b in zip(A, B)
[0.3799999999999999, 0.0, 0.0, 9.409999999999998, 1.25, 0.0]
```

A soma dos valores: `11.04`.

> Veja o código funcionando no [**Repl.it**](https://repl.it/FeV0/0).

Comment: Aparentemente resolveu o problema. Obrigado pela ajuda!

Comment: Pessoas, sejam como o @Anderson e expliquem o que estão fazendo quando responderem as perguntas. Principalmente em one liners. :-)   +1