# Soma de cada elemento de duas listas

Tags: python, lista

Existe algum código que soma os elementos de duas lista, por exemplo:

```
A=[1,2,3,4]

B=[2,4,5,6]

D=[3,6,8,10] # o elemento 3 e a soma dos elementos 1 e 2 da lista A e B
```

Comment: Possível duplicata de [Cálcula da soma da diferença entre 2 listas em Python](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/183198/c%c3%a1lcula-da-soma-da-diferen%c3%a7a-entre-2-listas-em-python)

Comment: Outra: [Soma de elementos em listas](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/197452/5878)

Answer (score 5):

A solução mais direta é utilizar a função nativa [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) que permite juntar/mesclar dois iteráveis.

```
zip(iteravel1, iteravel2)
```

O resultado é um objeto que quando iterado funciona como uma lista de tuplas, em que cada tupla tem um elemento de cada um dos iteráveis. No exemplo acima cada tupla iria ter um elemento do `iteravel1` e outro elemento do `iteravel2`.

No seu código, assumindo que tem a lista `A` e `B` criada, bastaria fazer assim:

```
D = []
for elemA, elemB in zip(A, B):
    D.append(elemA + elemB) #adicionar em D a soma dos elementos de cada lista
```

Como o `zip` devolve uma lista de tuplas, o `for` está a capturar cada um dos elementos da tupla em `elemA` e `elemB`

Se quiser tornar o código mais compacto e simples pode utilizar [*list comprehensions*](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions):

```
D = [elemA + elemB for elemA, elemB in zip(A, B)]
```

O `zip` suporta qualquer quantidade de iteráveis a juntar/mesclar. No seu exemplo poderia fazer a soma entre 3 listas com base no mesmo `zip`:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [2, 4, 5, 6]
C = [3, 6, 7, 8]

D = [elemA + elemB + elemC for elemA, elemB, elemC in zip(A, B, C)]
print(D) # [6, 12, 15, 18]
```

É importante também dizer que consegue resolver sem utilizar `zip` mas não ficaria tão intuitivo e direto. Uma solução seria:

```
D = [B[posicao] + elemA for posicao, elemA in enumerate(A)]
```

Neste ultimo exemplo iterei sobre o `A` obtendo quer o elemento quer a posição através de [`enumerate`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#enumerate) e depois com base na posição fui buscar o elemento correspondente em `B`.

[Veja todos estes exemplos no Ideone](https://ideone.com/lO4Dkr)

Comment: Sugestão: sendo um pouco chato aos detalhes, mas o retorno de `zip` não é uma *lista*, mas um objeto *zip*, que é iterável, assim eu alteraria "devolve uma lista" para "devolve um objeto iterável" xD

Comment: @AndersonCarlosWoss Eu agradeço o comentário como sempre. No entanto fui literal à documentação *"This function returns a list of tuples, where the i-th tuple contains the i-th element from each of the argument sequences or iterables"*. Mas confirmando no interpretador, o retorno é de facto um objeto zip. Vou refrasear ligeiramente, tentando não perder o sentido original. Vê depois se achas que ficou bom..

Answer (score 2):

```
A = [ 1, 2, 3, 4 ]
B = [ 2, 4, 5, 6 ]

D = [ (a + b) for a, b in zip(A, B) ]

print(D)
```

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar a função própria do Python, `map()`.

Ela recebe dois valores, uma ação e um alvo: `map(ação, alvo)`
usando uma lambda simples você tem o resultado numa linha simples:

```
A = [1, 2, 3, 4]
B = [2, 4, 5, 6]

soma = list(map(lambda v1, v2: v1 + v2, A, B))

print(soma)
```

Obs. 1: Perceba que converti o resultado da função `map` numa lista.

Obs. 2: Perceba que dentro de `map` tem uma lambda e "os alvos" que neste caso são A e B, mas poderia ser uma lista com um conjunto de números.

Answer (score 0):

Esse código funciona apenas se o array A tiver o mesmo tamanho ou ser menor que o array B:

```
 a=[1,2,3,4]
 b=[2,4,5,6]
 d=[]
 for x,y in enumerate(a): # Percorre o Array a enumerando suas posições
     d.append(y+b[x]) # somando elemento do array a com o elemento de mesma posição no array B
 print (d)
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra opção seria isso aqui:

```
D = map(sum, zip(A, B))
```

basicamente uma forma reduzida das outras respostas.

Comment: Vale citar que, neste caso, `D` não será uma lista, mas sim um gerador.